# When assigning a property which was casted literally the, the literal type is perserved for the new property/variable

Tags: typescript

I defined

```
const MODE = {
    NONE: 0 as 0, 
    COMPLETED: 1 as 1, 
    DELETED: 2 as 2 
} as const 
// It's a CreateReactApp project so enums aren't available
```

I was surprised to see that those types will now stick on assignment.

```
let mode = MODE.NONE
let someNumber = 5
```

type of mode is defined as 0, while the type of "someNumber" is defined as number.  If I copy a final value into a let variable there is a good chance I want to modify it, otherwise I'd just use the original.

The solution is to type the variable:

```
let mode: number = MODE.NONE // or a more specific type: typeof MODE[keyof typeof MODE]
```

But I would still like to understand why it was designed this way. In what scenario is it helpful to preserve a literal type when assigning a value to a let variable, or to a property which isn't defined as readonly?

Answer (score 1):

I think we should look at it from a different angle. Generally when inferring from assignments types should be preserved. It is the exception that the assignment changes the type such as widening of a literal type.

Let's consider the flowing example :

```
let MODE = { NONE: 0 as 0 }
let mode = MODE.NONE // still 0
const NONE = 0; // 
let mode2 = NONE; // number
```

If the type came from a `const` declaration, it makes sense that the type would be widened on assignment, since you probably would want to assign the const to a variable and then mutate it further

Before `as const` assertions, the only way you could get a literal type inside an object, was by using an assertion or an explicit type annotation, so it makes sense the compiler would preserver this explicit user request. `as const` introduces the complication that the assertion is no longer on the values, so it isn't as explicit anymore, but preserving the type in one case and not in the other might prove a bit too surprising.

**How does this work ?**

From what I can tell going through compiler code, there is a hidden property of a type that is tracked that is called freshness. If a literal type is fresh, then it will get widened on assignment. If a literal type is no longer fresh, it will be preserved. When assigning a property to an object freshness in removed. This is why the type is widened sometimes but not always:

```
let MODE = { NONE: 0 as 0 }
let mode = MODE.NONE // still 0, typeof MODE.NONE is not fresh
const NONE = 0; // 
let mode2 = NONE; // number, NONE is fresh so widened
```